# Add External NIC to Virtual Switch Manager

Tags: virtual-machine, network-adapter

I've setup a HP ProLiant MicroServer Gen8 as my home NAS. All has been well except I've noticed there's been terrible latency (~150ms) from within my local network. I'm running Windows Core 2012 using the Gen8 as my host and I have a couple of VM's managed with Hyper-V Manager.

Research tells me that it's a known issue with Broadcom NICs and people suggested to just use Intel NICs.

Do they mean replace the physical NIC's or just update the drivers?
If so, will it show up in the Virtual Switch Manager drop down list when setting a connection type?

Excuse my ignorance if this is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I worded my question terribly.

I found out the fix for my terrible ping...Disable-NetAdapterVmq!